# Move files & folders in github

Tags: git, github

I need to set up a github for a school project but Im getting lost in the complicated workings of it.

I managed to push the contents of a folder to my repository but since I need to add other files and want to keep some structure I want to take the current files & folder I have and move them into a new directory.

For example, I want to change the following:

```
Master
  Folder X
  Folder Y
  File Z
```

To

```
Master
  Project 1
    Folder X
    Folder Y
    File Z
```

How do I do this exactly? I've found similar posts with similar explanations but I never understood any of them.. Could some please explain this in an easy fashion? Because I've been trying without success for nearly two hours now.

Comment: `mkdir Project_1; git mv Folder_X Folder_Y File_Z Project_1/`

Comment: Do I enter this code in gitbash?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This does not appear to be working for folders. Do you know how I can delete folders out of my repository so I can upload them in a correct way?

Comment: I hope you're not planning on adding `Project2` to the same repository!

Comment: I was planning on adding a second folder under my master yes, would that be a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move files as you want in your local folder

and after that simply commit all changes in git bash:

```
git add "Project 1"
git commit -am "change folders layout"
```

and push changes:

```
git push
```

Comment: You'll want to `git mv`, not just `mv`.

Comment: Git handles it either way

Comment: @exussum: Actually, that's true (I hadn't noticed this answer includes `git add` before the `git commit`).

Comment: @webSpider I might have done something wrong and I ended up deleting all my files. I am now going to push them again but directly into the correct folder. Do I just do this by using this command?  
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository/folder.git ?

Comment: you'll need git commit and git push after that.

Answer (score 1):

just change github.com with github.dev in the link you see on your repository, you will go to the editor and you can do it in a simple way